# Installing Gulp created large node_modules and package-lock files

Tags: npm, gulp, node-modules, package.json, package-lock.json

I have just installed Gulp in a fresh, empty project and followed the instructions in the [getting started guide](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/getting-started.md). I'm not sure if I've done it right or not though as after running `npm init` and `npm install --save-dev gulp` I had a very large `node_modules` folder (198 items) and `package-lock.json` file (2419 lines).

Is this normal or have I gone wrong somewhere?